# TextView con distinto texto según el idioma

Tags: java, android, xml

Estoy haciendo un menú en mi app que tiene un selector de idioma en el mismo. Para poner los textos de ese menú en el idioma que esté elegido en ese momento estaba haciendo lo siguiente:

```
    int checkedRadioButtonId = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radio=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
 if(checkedRadioButtonId==R.id.Español)
        {
            barra=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            barra.setTitle("Configuración");

            titulo1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.autoarranuqe);
            titulo1.setText("Autoarranque");
        }
        else
        {
            barra=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            barra.setTitle("Configuration");

            titulo1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.autoarranuqe);
            titulo1.setText("Autorun");
        }
```

No obstante, a menos que ponga el texto directamente en el .xml, este no aparece, y ahí solo puedo poner uno de los textos. ¿Qué otra manera se puede utilizar para que haya distintos textos según el idioma? ¿Habría que hacer 2 xml distintos para cada pantalla (una en español y otra en inglés)?

Answer (score 0):

Hacer esto `barra.setTitle("Configuration");` es un error muy grande, siempre se debe acceder a través del array(recurso) de valores string (res/values/strings.xml)

En Java: R.string.string_name

En XML: @string/string_name

Código: getString(R.string.string_name);

Aquí te dejo un enlace:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html?hl=es-419

De todos modos, android studio te trae ya una herramienta para traducir (lo único que hace es crear el xml del sitio seleccionado, y ya el teléfono solo usará el que tenga puesto o si no lo encuentra el que tiene por defecto)

Comment: Sí, eso lo he cambiado. En ese caso, ¿puedo darle distintos valores desde el if los valores del string mediante R.string.string_name para que su valor varíe según el idioma?

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que crear un archivo strings.xml por cada uno de los idiomas que quieras tener. Dentro de cada carpeta values-[idioma] (Android studio lo hace por vos).
Una vez hecho esto, al llamar a R.string.string_name. Android utiliza el archivo de recursos de acuerdo con el idioma que disponga el dispositivo.
Es decir el if lo que haria seria manipular una variable de tipo Locale para cambiar al nuevo idioma.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html?hl=es-419

Comment: En ese caso, entiendo que dentro de values, debo meter el archivo strings dentro de otra carpeta llamada idioma y hacer dos archivos de este tipo, uno para un idioma y otro para el otro, ¿Verdad? Pero la cuestión es, ¿Cómo le asigno el R.strting correspondiente a cada elemento desde el .java en el if?

Comment: Por lo que leo en el enlace que has pasado, este sistema coge el string de un idioma u otro según el idioma del S.O, pero yo quiero que lo haga según la elección del usuario. ¿Hay manera de hacer esto?

Comment: Exacto, la eleccion de la cadena la hace el SO segun el idioma. Para que lo haga segun la eleccion del usuario podes hacer algo como esto:
`Locale localizacion;
if(idioma español)
 localizacion = new Locale("es", "ES");
else
localizacion = new Locale("en", "EN");
Locale.setDefault(localizacion);
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setLocale(localizacion);
 appContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,appContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
getActivity().recreate();`
Resumiendo, asignas una conf con nuevo idioma y recreas la actividad

Comment: Ademas deberias guardar la preferencia del usuario, con shared preferences por ejemplo. para que al iniciar la aplicacion se muestre el idioma correspondiente